# Showing seclusion of $\ell^2$ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Let $$\ell^2:= \left\{x:=(x_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} \; \text{ with } x_j \in \mathbb{R} \; \text{ and } \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(x_j)^2 < \infty \right\}$$
and define the operations
$$\lambda x := (\lambda x_j)_j \; \; \text{ und } x +y:= (x_j+y_j)_j$$

The task is to show that $l^2$ is a vector space.

For this I have to first of all show that for every $(x,y) \in \ell^2 \times \ell^2$ the composition $+: \ell^2 \times \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ and the mapping $\cdot: \mathbb{R} \times \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ is well-defined and then check the axioms for a vector space.
However, I don't get that in the first case $$\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(x_j+y_j)^2 = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\left[ (x_j)^2 + 2x_jy_j + (y_j)^2 \right] < \infty$$ under the conditions $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(x_j)^2 < \infty$ and $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(y_j)^2 < \infty$.

I don't know anything about convergency (not even absolute convergency) of the series $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\left[ (x_j)^2 + 2x_jy_j + (y_j)^2 \right]$ and so I can't permutate the series like I want to somehow use the assumption, e.g. I could write $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(x_j)^2 + \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}(y_j)^2 +   \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty}2x_jy_j$ if absolute convergency was existent, but this is not necessarily the case here.

Do you have an idea?

X3nius

Comment: Hint: $(x_i-y_i)^2 \geq 0$ implies $x_i^2 + y_i^2 \geq 2x_iy_i $

Comment: @DionelJaime
Okay then we can conclude that $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} 2x_jy_j \le \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j^2 + \sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} y_j^2 < \infty$, however this does not necessarily imply absolute convergence of $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} 2x_jy_j$ (therefore we must have $2|x_jy_j| \le x_j^2 + y_j^2)$, so that in the end the whole series $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} [x_j^2 + 2x_jy_j + y_j^2]$ is absolute convergent?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. The series you asked about converges. The proof is as you said. If you're asking whether or not the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2x_jy_j $ converges absolutely, the answer is yes. You can show $2|x_jy_j| \leq x_j^2 + y_j^2$. I don't understand the connection between this and the original question.  If you're instead asking if the $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j^2 + 2x_jy_j + y_j^2 $ is absolutely convergent, the answer is also yes. All the terms are positive since $x_j^2 + 2x_jy_j + y_j^2 = (x_j + y_j)^2$, so of course.

Comment: Your last commend nailed it!